# Data context cannot see tables in db, EF Core in WPF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I try to create WPF application using Entity Framework Core. I have created my database (all of tables are correctly configured in SQL Server). I wrote my DbContext like below:

```
    internal class DbsDataModel : DbContext
    {
        private const string connectionString =
            "Server=Serv;Database=DbLibraryManager;Trusted_Connection=true;";

        public DbSet<LibDataModel>? libraries;
        public DbSet<Admin>? Admins;
        public DbSet<Worker>? Workers;
        public DbSet<User>? Users;

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<LibDataModel>()
                .ToTable("libraries", x => x.ExcludeFromMigrations()).HasKey(x => x.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Admin>().ToTable("Admins").HasKey(x => x.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Worker>().ToTable("Workers").HasKey(x => x.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users").HasKey(x => x.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<LibDataModel>().HasMany(x => x.Admins).WithOne(x => x.Library);
            modelBuilder.Entity<LibDataModel>().HasMany(x => x.Workers).WithOne(x => x.Library);
            modelBuilder.Entity<LibDataModel>().HasMany(x => x.Users).WithOne(x => x.Library);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

but when I'm trying to operate on data, programm gets an exception "Value cannot be null - table_name". It is really weird, because in my register system in this app everything work correctly. I would glad for your help, most of EF Core tutorials is only for ASP.NET.

EDIT:
Thank you very much guys, I should to use "defoult" instead nullable operator, but maybe someone knows, why still I cannot get records from database? I use code like below:

```
        public static LibDataModel ReturnLibraryWithThisNip(int nip)
        {
            try
            {
                var lib = new LibDataModel();

                using (var dataContext = new DbsDataModel())
                {
                    dataContext.Database.OpenConnection();

                    var listOfLibs = dataContext.libraries.ToList();

                    if (listOfLibs.Any(x => x.NipNumber == nip))
                        lib = listOfLibs.Where(x => x.NipNumber == nip).First();

                    else throw new Exception();

                    dataContext.Database.CloseConnection();
                }

                return lib;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

and I'm sure, that a record with value, that I give during tests exist.

Comment: Which line it is the error pointing?

Comment: Error pointing is in the class, which manages data.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's it but your DbSet properties looks weird to me.

They are not properties and why are they nullable?

Does changing your DbSet's to this help?

```
public DbSet<LibDataModel> libraries { get; set; }
public DbSet<Admin> Admins { get; set; }
public DbSet<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Comment: I think DbSet has to be nullable, because sometime some table can be empty. What if I would like to check in code, does any DbSet is empty?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's empty or not. DbSet represents a table, not the first or any row in it for that matter. How would you add rows to your table if it's null because it's empty?

Comment: if you have nullable references enabled, you may have to "cheat" the nullabillity detection with `public DbSet<LibDataModel> libraries { get; set; } = default!` to let the compiler know it's not going to be null. It won't be null, because the base class of DbContext will set the properties for you

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you very much! But still LINQ query                     lib = dataContext.libraries.ToList().Where(x => x.NipNumber == nip)
                        .First(); does not return any value. ;(

Comment: It is enough to declare `public DbSet<Admin> Admins => Set<Admin>();` And theoretically it may speedup `DbContext` instantiation, because it is not needed to initialise all DbSet properties, which  EF Core should do to avoid Null Reference Exception.